# iOS : sort information base on date Modified on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a UITableView that I got information from server, I want to sort my information based on Date Modified, would you please help me in this implementation, how can I sort it?

Thanks in advance! appreciated any code in answer part!

my date modified from json is like

```
 "dateModified": "2014-06-23T07:51:08.373Z"
```

my ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
_mapView.delegate = self;

[ApiManager fetchCoordinates:^(id result) {
    newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    NSArray *array=(NSArray*)result;

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
    {

        MyAnnotation *newAnnotation;

        newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
        newAnnotation.company = dictionary[@"company"];
        newAnnotation.dateModified = dictionary[@"dateModified"];


        [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
    }
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];

} failure:^(NSError *error) {

}];
}
```

my table view controller

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


MyAnnotation *newAnnotation=[newAnnotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newAnnotation.company];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newAnnotation.dateModified];


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your array. Try something like this:

```
 self.sortedArray = [newAnnotations sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
 MyAnnotation* ann1 = (MyAnnotation*)obj1;
 MyAnnotation* ann2 = (MyAnnotation*)obj2;

 NSComparisonResult result = [ann1.dateModified compare:ann2.dateModified]
 return result;
```

}];

Where sortedArray is a private property:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sortedArray;
```

Also, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, alloc new cells only if you can't dequeue them.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    MyAnnotation *newAnnotation=[self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newAnnotation.company];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newAnnotation.dateModified];


    return cell;
}
```

And note that the date comparison I'm making is actually a string comparison and it works only because your date is formatted YYYY-MM-DD.

Please not that I didn't test this piece of code, so take it more like a general direction and don't just copy-paste it.

Comment: thank you for the comment where should i put the firt part, I mean sorting array ?

Comment: you could put it in viewDidLoad, for example

Comment: sorry for the question but how to use sortedArray?

Comment: Oh, yeah.. I edited the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath in my answer. You just use sortedArray instead of your newAnntations array. To be able to access sortedArray from that method, you could make it a private property of the class.